Discord.py command don't work with parameter
i recently added a parameter to my slashcommand in discord, and since the command refuses to work. i get no response from the bot. the first code block works fine, but the second one doesnt.
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class AttendanceCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    
    @app_commands.command(description='see which rolemembers are in your voicechannel')
    async def attendance(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Attendance command received without parameter")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(AttendanceCog(bot))

import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class AttendanceCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    
    @app_commands.command(description='see which rolemembers are in your voicechannel')
    @app_commands.describe(test='test')
    async def attendance(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, test: str):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Attendance command received with parameter: {test}")
        
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(AttendanceCog(bot))

when i type "/attendance something" i expect the bot to say "Attendance command received with parameter: something"
I get error message in discord: The application did not respond

pretty much this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yx5YYmKeFgc
apparently you have to sync the slash commands AND restart discord.
and for some reason running bot.tree.sync() works while bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild.id) does not...
you would expect forcing your specific guild to sync would work better. but apparently not.
also, run discord in browser instead of app so you can just refresh page instead of restarting the app.

Your code works fine for me, in order to add new applications commands in discord.py you must run client.tree.sync() or in your case bot.tree.sync(). You do not have to sync commands after each edit only when implementing a new command.
I suggest you create a /sync command which does the sync so that you do not get rate limited when testing.
If you are still having issues with this, check your console/terminal for any errors you get either on runtime or upon execution of the app command and if you are still stuck reply with the errors.
